# ListPreference with Image in Live Wallpaper android (ImageListPreference)

Tags: android

Can any one give me example of ListPreference with images i have googled but could not find out i have done successfully with only listview by searching but how to put image also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Google results :

#1 http://www.cmwmobile.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=12

#2 [How to add icons to Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765186/how-to-add-icons-to-preference) [recommended]