# How can I intent a subscreen (PreferenceScreen) from a Preference from xml or programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-preferences

I am using the custom IconPreferenceScreen from previous solutions
[How to add icons to Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765186/how-to-add-icons-to-preference)
to get the Icon in the preference but now I want to intent a subscreen in that element something like, from preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen>

<org.mypackage.IconPreferenceScreen 
            android:title="IconPreferenceScreen Title"
            android:summary="IconPreferenceScreen Summary"
            android:key="key1"

   <intent>
      <PreferenceScreen
         android:key="sub1"
         android:title="sub"
         android:persistent="false"/>
    <intent />

  />

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

I know in the above there has to be some action in the intent, I just want to show what I want to intent, whether it is from xml or programmatically. Note that I do not want to have separate PreferenceActivity classes neither preferences.xml