# How would I add a Google Plus One button to the settings of an Android lwp?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, live-wallpaper

How would I add a Google Plus One button to my Android live wallpapers settings like the following?

[image: Plus One button in settings]

Comment: How your setting are implemented? Do You know about this possibilities http://youtu.be/49pWckcaZEI?t=25m38s ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that video but it doesn't work the way they suggest in that video. Thank you though.

Comment: At which exact point it doesn't work as described on the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is how I would do it, I haven't tested it just searched over Google.

- You will have to use the Google Plus API, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app) you can see how to add `+1` button to a layout in the accepted answer.
- Now you know how to add `+1` button, to add this to your preference screen you have to create a `Preference` item with a custom layout which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194116/creating-a-custom-layout-for-preferences). In this custom layout you put the previously created layout with the `+1` button and then you add it to your Preference List.
- Now you have a `Preference` item with a custom layout with a `+1` button, just add an `onClickListener` to the `Preference` item with the `+1` button and using [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/%20%22%22) do whatever you want when user clicks it!

Another way is to add Google Plus icon to the preference:

- Create a `Preference` item and add Google Plus icon to it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765186/how-to-add-icons-to-preference%20%22%22).
- Add an `onClickListener` to the `Preference` item and using [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/%20%22%22) do whatever you want when user clicks it.

Hope this can help you! Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: I'm having trouble adding my code, too much to indent, but I would like to show it to you so you can see where I am stuck. I have a custom preference that someone shared with me, unfortunately it has an import that no longer exists. I am using the most recent Google Play Services API. The import is import com.google.android.gms.plus.b; ".b" no longer exists and I can't figure out what it was or is now. My email is steve.curtis.jr@gmail.com if you can email me I can send you my code.