# Add icon to preference in older version

Tags: android, icons, preference

After Android 3.0 we can add icon to preference using preference.setIcon(icon). how can i add icons to preference to support older versions than Android 3.0? 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Preference.setIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) was only added in API 11, to add icons to preference in older Android versions you could clone the `IconPreferenceScreen` and then import to you project. You will need to make a few changes to load custom attributes.

After that you can just use the new IconPreferenceScreen in place of a Preference, and add an icon.

[IconPreferenceScreen source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/37f06a4/src/com/android/settings/IconPreferenceScreen.java)

Comment: thank for the reply. i tried to use IconPreferenceScreen class. i found another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765186/how-to-add-icons-to-preference. so i tried to work like explain in there. but it just so only empty space. can you give some suggestion to make this work?

Comment: check if drawable is not null in the constructor where you retrieve the drawable

Comment: it is set. but problem is there is no even title or summary.

Comment: could you put your xml preferences file?
which api version are you testing?